# Drawing a triangle with a loop using 4 integer inputs

Tags: c++, loops, geometry, shapes

I have a loop that prints a 25 x 25 grid and is supposed to draw a triangle using 2 x-coordinates and 2 y-coordinates from user input where x1 < x2 and y1 < y2.  It also uses two characters input by the user to fill the interior and outline the exterior of the shape.  The reason for using 4 coordinates is because the other part of the assignment is supposed to use these inputs to draw a rectangle.  I have the rectangle working perfectly.

I'm using the same loop to print the grid for both shapes, but I cannot figure out how to adjust the if statements that determine the placement of the two characters to make a triangle.

Here is the loop for the triangle.  The if statements in the middle draw a rectangle.  Any ideas on adjustments to make it print a triangle instead?

```
void Triangle::printTriangle()
{
int numrows = 25;
int numcols = 25;
int current_row = numrows; // starting row number
int current_col = 1; // starting col number
char output = '.';

for(i = 0; i < numrows; i++)        // prints 25 rows of 25 dots 
{   

    cout << current_row << '\t';    // Print out current row number, followed by a tab

    //This is our loop for each ROW
    //Print out dots in each row OR stuff for the triangle
    for(j = 1; j <= numcols; j++)
    {           
        output = '.'; // Initialize output with our default value of "."


        if ((current_col >= x1) && (current_col <= x2) && (current_row >= y1) && (current_row <= y2))
        {
            output = outer;
        }

        if ((current_col > x1) && (current_col < x2) && (current_row > y1) && (current_row < y2))
        {
            output = inner;
        }

        cout << output << "  "; // output our "output" value and a space            
        current_col++;  //Increment current column, because this is the end of this column loop iteration

    } // Close column loop

    cout << endl;       //...and a new line

    current_col = 1;    // reset column count for next iteration
    current_row--;      // decrement current row number

} // Close Row loop


//output column labels across bottom line
cout << '\t';

// put 1 -> 25 across the bottom
for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
{
    if(i < 10)
    {
        cout << i << "  ";
    }

    if(i > 9)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}

// Spit out a couple of blank lines
cout << endl << endl;
```

}

Comment: I think you are missing a key point in your above description, as there is no way to describe a general triangle with only 4 numbers (at least on a cartesian 2-dimensional plane). There must be some additional assumptions about one or more of the sides being aligned on the grid or something...

Comment: The assumption is it will be a right triangle and the value for y2 will be the vertex above the right angle and the value for x1 will be the vertex to the left of the right angle.  Also, I believe I figured out the adjustments to the if statements.  Adding (current_row <= to current_col) to both if statements seems to have been what I was missing.  Still testing it though.

Comment: Well these adjustments only work some of the time.

Comment: Given those assumptions, the right angle corner should be at (x2, y1) (bottom right of the triangle, with the hypotenuse to the left and above), and the other corners would be (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), right?